# why readline() is not efficient

Tags: python

I have read at many places that best way to read a file is :-

```
with open(filename) as fo:
    for line in fo:
      print fo
```

Because it will read only one line at a time in memory, and it allow us to process one line at a time and then read next line.

I believe same should be true for fo.readline(), It should also read only one line at a time in memory.

Aprt from handling end of file and automatically closing file object, Do you guys see any other advantage of

```
for line in fo:
      print fo
```

over

```
fo.readline()
```

Comment: It less to type, for one.

Comment: `for line in fo: print fo` reads every line and prints it, `fo.readline()` reads one line and does not print it. Do you mean `fo.readlines()` or something else?

Comment: I believe you heard `fo.readlines` is inefficent. It loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: I mean fo.readline(), which will count one line at a time, If we know number of line in a file then we can use it to read entire file. or If we have to read first 5 line of a file then also we can use fo.readline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the docs for `file.next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines
>     of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a **hidden
>     read-ahead buffer**. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining
>     next() with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right.

`for line in fo` implicitly calls `fo.next()`, so,

```
for line in fo:
    ...
```

uses a hidden read-ahead buffer, which improves the I/O performance. If you use
`readline()` instead, you do not get the performance benefit of the read-ahead buffer.

---

Let's test the above claim on a random (480K) file:

```
def using_next(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            pass

def using_iter_next(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in iter(f.next, ''):
            pass

def using_iter_readline(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
            pass

def using_while_readline(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break

In [164]: %timeit using_next('data')
1000 loops, best of 3: 320 µs per loop

In [173]: %timeit using_iter_next('data')
1000 loops, best of 3: 531 µs per loop

In [171]: %timeit using_iter_readline('data')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop

In [170]: %timeit using_while_readline('data')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.21 ms per loop
```

Comment: @remus: [`%timeit` repeats the function call](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/timeit.py#L297) a sufficient number of times for `0.2 seconds <= total time < 2.0 seconds`. Since `100*2.21 ms` exceeds 0.2 seconds, there were only 100 loops performed.

Comment: Ah, crazy ok. Makes sense! Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to call `fo.readline()` once per line. The standard distinction is between

```
for line in fo.readlines():
    print line
```

which reads the entire file into memory and

```
for line in fo:
    print line
```

which is far more efficient in terms of memory.

A `for` loop iterates over an iterator, which a `file` object happens to be. The loop above is the simpler equivalent of

```
for line in iter(fo.readline, ''):
    print line
```

or the less exotic but more verbose

```
while True:
    line = fo.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```